# A question about the comparability of large cardinals.

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Are there any examples of two large cardinal axioms $AX$ and $AY$, in the language of first order $ZFC$, which satisfy the following conditions.

1. Each of them defines a unique cardinal number - $C(AX)$ for $AX$
   and $C(AY)$ for $AY$ - not like the axiom of measurable cardinals which defines a whole collection of cardinal numbers.
2. If $T$ denotes the theory $ZFC+AX+AY$, then $T$ has not yet been proved inconsistent.
3. $T$ proves that each of $C(AX)$ and $C(AY)$ is larger that the smallest strongly inaccessible cardinal number.
4. The sentences of $T$ stating that $C(AX) < C(AY)$ and that $C(AY) < C(AX)$ are each consistent with $T$, if $T$ is consistent.

Comment: Somehow I lost condition (4). It stated that the sentences of T which assert that C(AX)<C(AY) and that C(AY)<C(AX) are each 
consistent with T, if T is consistent.

Comment: There is quite an issue with using `<` adjacent to another letter (without spacing), the parser usually truncates the post at that point. I edited that and added LaTeX, let me know if I did something wrong. Also, for future reference: line breaks are good; copy paste from a post on some other board/email/etc without any editing: not as good.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what constitutes a large cardinal axiom for you. Otherwise you could take AX to assert the existence of a third strongly inaccessible cardinal and AY to assert the existence of the maximum of the second strong inaccessible and the continuum. Then conditions 1-3 are satisfied and 4 can be forced either way.

Comment: Miha: You meant weakly, not strongly, inaccessible, since all strongly inaccessible cardinals are greater than the continuum.

Comment: Andreas, you're right, which unfortunately makes my comment inapplicable.

Comment: An example to underscore the problem that Miha Habic has pointed out:  Let AX = "there exists a third largest inaccessible", AY = "there exists a k-th inaccessible, where k=2 if CH, and k=4 if non-CH". 

Formally, these are large cardinal axioms, though the second one is really silly.  

Comment: What does condition 4 mean exactly? Should the consistency of each inequality follow from T+Con(T)?  You can easily cheat to fulfill that, by increasing the strength of AX, without changing C(AX). 

(E.g., change "there exists a second smallest inaccessible" to 
"... with a supercompact above", and you can still define C(AX) to be the second smallest inaccessible.) 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let AX = "there exists a least strongly compact cardinal", and let AY be "there exists a least whatever cardinal" (there are many possibilities for "whatever", e.g., "inaccessible  with a measurable below it" if you want to be modest).

C(AX) = the least strongly compact, C(AY) = the least whatever, say the least inaccessible past the least measurable.

It is well known (Magidor) that the least strongly compact can be the least supercompact or the least measurable. In the first case, C(AX) is much larger than C(AY), in the second case, slightly smaller.

(Arthur Apter has written several papers about this "identity crisis of strongly compacts".  Many more examples in the same spirit can be obtained from his results.)

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63735/a-question-about-large-cardinal-axioms

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to me how many examples can be constructed
of pairs of large cardinal axioms (which cannot be proved in ZFC) and which satisfy my conditions. I am trying to get a picture of
how far up into the set-theoretical hierarchy one can reach with a collection C of large cardinal axioms whose cardinal numbers are
totally ordered by size, and whose conjunction is not known to be
inconsistent with ZFC. Pairs of axioms which satisfy my conditions
should probably not both belong to C.


Comment: I must also thank you, Asaf, for doing such a wonderful editing job
on my post. I had no idea what to do to get out of the mess I had made with the end of it.
